# Perl, SVN::Hooks, and SVN::Hooks::Notify

Tags: perl, svn

Can anyone tell me offhand if SVN::Hooks::Notify's NOTIFY and NOTIFY_DEFAULTS blocks replace (or rather, stop the evaluation of) the POST_COMMIT block?  My PRE_COMMIT block works fine, and my existing NOTIFY/NOTIFY_DEFAULTS blocks process just fine.

However, nothing I have under the POST_COMMIT block fires at all... and yes, hooks/post-commit is linked to the script.  The perdocs for svn::hooks::notify state that it runs within POST_COMMIT, but I would prefer to do some extra processing first *before* kicking off a notification email (eg, inserting pertinent information into a db table for later use).

Answer (score 1):

The NOTIFY block sets a post-commit hook; there is no separate hook for notify.

And as far as I can tell from the SVN::Hook source, you can have set as many of a given hook as you want, and they will run in the order you add them in.  So you may need to do e.g.:

```
use SVN::Hooks;
BEGIN {
    POST_COMMIT { ... }
}
use SVN::Hooks::Notify;
```

to have your other hook come before the notify hook.